# Android studio crashes when trying to open an existing project

Tags: android, android-studio

Something weird is happening with my android studio or project and I dont understand what the problem is or how to fix it.

When I open android studio it defaults opens a project, this works correctly and the project is loaded. When I try to open an existing project from android studio it loads the project and with that I mean its popping up with normal indexing files... dialog but just after the indexing android studio crashes(Closes the  application).

The weird thing is I have been working in that project for about 2 weeks now with no problem and all of the sudden its crashing when I want to open it.

I am running Windows 7 64 bit and android studio 2.2.3.

I checked the idea log generated please see link :
[Idea.log](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rei012ixv8eg3p7/idea.log?dl=0)

And noticed this error :

```
java.lang.Throwable: java.io.IOException: org.iq80.snappy.CorruptionException: Invalid copy offset for opcode starting at 1
```

I don't know what is causing this, Don't understand it It was working and just stopped.I don't know if its memory related or something that's corrupt.

Comment: try recent (no stable, but stable :) builds to see if this is still happening. Get it from here: http://tools.android.com/download/studio - if you still will be facing the issue report it here: http://tools.android.com/filing-bugs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your project is messed up! , maybe because of virus or improper handling of the data , some files in your project is got corrupted. To solve this best way is to create a new project and copy paste the code by opening old project in some text editor like notepad++ just to copy and clone exactly the same as your did while making the original one its not answer you are expecting but it will at least get your project up and running

Comment: At the end what I had to do is to create a new blank project in android studio and then I used the windows explorer to navigate to my old project files(the project that crashed) then I copied all the files from the old project to the new one and now it works. I did not know that it will just work if you copy all the files usually there's issues. This solution was not ideal but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try to import the messed up AS project instead of creating a new one.. It works for me.. Solved in few minutes..